# VS Code Remote-SSH: The vscode server failed to start SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server via `remote-ssh extension` for **Visual Studio Code**, however, I'm getting the following error:

> The vscode server failed to start SSH

Everything is fine on the server-side, and the connection to this host worked fine for a while.

Any suggestions to re-access the server via `remote-ssh extension`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

After a while, I found a solution that can be useful to others.

In **VS Code** press:

> CTRL + SHIFT + P

Type or select the option:

> Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host...

[image]

Select the host name:

[image]

And after this procedure, try connecting again to the host.

That worked for me.

Comment: Worked! Do you know why this is needed?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you! To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why this is needed, but it seems to be a common solution for some remote SSH connection issues in VS Code.s

Comment: Huge plus! You saved my time @whoisraibolt

Comment: About how to force restart remote server: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_cleaning-up-the-vs-code-server-on-the-remote

Comment: I am getting the same error as you got initially. Unfortunately Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host does not work for me, at least I still get the same error.  Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host did not fix the problem for me either

Answer (score 36):

**For people who are here after Feb 1st, 2024**:

The [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_86) of the new VS-Code 1.86 (Jan 2024) reads:

> From this release onwards, VS Code desktop is only compatible with Linux distributions based on glibc 2.28 or later, and glibcxx 3.4.25 or later, such as Debian 10, RHEL 8, or Ubuntu 20.04.

If you don't have the required version of the mentioned programs on the server side, you better revert to the previous version of VS-Code (v1.85). To do so, uninstall your current (v1.86) VS-Code, download v1.85 from the link below, and install it.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85

Linux users can easily run the following command until the next release; run it after you uninstall the current (v1.86) VS-Code:

```
sudo apt install code-exploration
```

Comment: This works, I only wish I had seen this earlier-- struggled through it and reverting the update was what eventually worked.

Comment: By setup, do you mean to just redownload the older version ```Downloads: Windows: x64 Arm64 | Mac: Universal Intel silicon | Linux: deb rpm tarball Arm snap```

Comment: I have had this same issue since the beginning of February as well. The above answers didn't work, but when I downloaded and installed 1.85, it worked again...

Comment: @GeorgeAdams Yes. Uninstall v1.86, download v1.85 from the link and install it. I edited the answer so there's less confusion.

Comment: @RosalieW I am not sure if I understand. My answer tells you to uninstall v1.86 and download and install v1.85.

Comment: worked for me too. I was struggling with the ssh keys, thinking that it was an issue with the keys.

Comment: @ahajianpour that is what I did -- I uninstalled 1.86 and went back to 1.85

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was ssh plugin issue. I updated remote ssh plugin then it worked

Comment: Current release version `v0.100` failed trying to connect to a raspberry pi. Deleting `~/.vscode-server` on the pi and using `v0.101.2023041015` (pre-release as of today) worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

> Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host...

Didn't work for me, so I tried the other option:

> Remote-SSH: Uninstall VS Code Server from Host...

It took a bit more time but worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

For raspberry pi this helped me https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8342#issuecomment-1501195063

> Ok so it seems I was able to find a workaround provided here.
>
> "I think you're having the same issue as me, but it's actually caused by an update to the pi. VScode is reading the uname -m value, the machine hardware name, which is returning aarch64, and so it is trying to run the 64 bit version of the remote server. In reality, your pi is likely using a armv7l (32 bit) user space. Remove the vscode remote server currently on the pi, then add arm_64bit=0 to /boot/config.txt and restart. If uname -m returns armv7l, then vscode should work again."
>
> - Remove vscode server from RPi: `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server` on the RPi.
> - Add the `arm_64bit=0` to `/boot/config.txt` and restart as stated above on the RPi.
> - Start your vscode again from the host and start your remote connection. This will download the correct server.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove vscode server config from home dir

- run `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server`
- then try connecting again, it worked for me

Comment: Do you know why this resolves the error?

Answer (score 1):

One other possible reason is **your remote machine may not have enough space**. So check that.

Answer (score 0):

wrong proxy setting may cause problem.
If Remote-SSH: kill VS Code Server on Host command not work for you, open settings and clear proxy setting and retry.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is fine on the server-side, and the connection to this host worked fine for a while.

In case it is a simple intermittent network issue, VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) will retry the connection for you (up to 5 times)

See [issue 127565](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127565) and [PR 156444](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/156444)

> ### Retry up to 5 times the initial authority resolving and also retry up to 5 times the initial connection
>
> When connecting to a remote, if the initial connection fails, we will give up. The idea was that retrying would be useless, since the initial setup might have failed.
>
> But it is possible that perhaps it was an intermittent network error.

This is available in [VSCode insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 0):

Update the Remote ssh
check file groups belongs to same group if you manually copied .vscode-server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you also have dev containers running on the remote host. You may fail to kill the vscode-server (thus somehow fail to reconnect) since the vscode-server in containers are running as root on the remote host. You need to first kill the running containers (`docker stop <container_name>`) and try reconnecting again.

Answer (score 0):

**For people who are here after Feb 10th, 2024 :**

Version 1.86.1 brings a temporary patch allowing VScode users to connect to unsupported OS version again (old Linux distributions). See the issue's conclusion : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/203375

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all methods provided by former answers, but none of them worked. Finally, the problem solve by the update of Vscode severse.